# Parsing a JSON Array with JavaScript returning selected parts

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, parsing

I have a very simple snipplet for a json array and a javascript function that now returns a single argument:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JSON Array Test</h2>

<p id="outputid"></p>

<script>
var arrayinput = '{"collection":[' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXA","secAttr":"13156161","lastAttr":"01" },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXB","secAttr":"11153325","lastAttr":"02"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"14431513","lastAttr":"03"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"161714","lastAttr":"01"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"151415","lastAttr":"02"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"114516","lastAttr":"02"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"131417","lastAttr":"03"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"1311865","lastAttr":"03"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"1314153","lastAttr":"01"  },' +
'{"firstAttr":"XXXC","secAttr":"13312163","lastAttr":"01"  }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(arrayinput);
document.getElementById("outputid").innerHTML =
obj.collection[1].firstAttr + " " + obj.collection[1].secAttr;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is that I don't want to return just one value but multiple ones. For example all entrys with `lastAttr=01` should be returned.

Therefore I would need something along the line of:

```
for(var i in obj) {                    
    if(lastAttr[i]="01") {
        document.getElementById("outputid").innerHTML =
        obj.collection[i].firstAttr + " " + obj.collection[i].secAttr;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Just curious, why are you embedding a string of JSON in your code? Or is this just a representation for the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform a *where* you need to use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filteredArr = arr.collection.filter(function(item) {
   return item.lastAttr == "01";
});
```

And, finally, you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate results and perform some action:

```
var outputElement = document.getElementById("outputid");
filteredArr.forEach(function(item) {
    // Check that I used insertAdyacentHtml to be sure that all items
    // will be in the UI!
  outputElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", item.firstAttr + " " + item.secAttr);
});
```

Also, you can do it *fluently*:

```js
var arr = {
  collection: [{
    firstAttr: "hello",
    secAttr: "world",
    lastAttr: "01"
  }, {
    firstAttr: "hello 2",
    secAttr: "world 2",
    lastAttr: "01"
  }]
};

var outputElement = document.getElementById("outputid");
var filteredArr = arr.collection.filter(function(item) {
  return item.lastAttr == "01";
}).forEach(function(item) {
  outputElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", item.firstAttr + " " + item.secAttr);
});
```

```html
<div id="outputid"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't tell people to use `.innerHTML += ...`. It causes such huge problems. Use `insertAdjacentHTML()` instead.

Comment: @squint Well, I can change this.. I didn't tell "use it". I said "you need to concatenate **at least**"...

Comment: I get a blank screen with no error message on the two above snipplets.

Comment: For some reason it is not writing to the p-block. Both of your answers @squint and yours have that problem. Am I missing somehting here?

Comment: @Thevagabond I've added a runnable sample

Comment: Found the mistake.... the + signs in the collection messed it up... I got rid of those and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the `collection` Array and append the new stuff. Right now you're iterating the outer object and overwriting the `.innerHTML` each time.

```
var out = document.getElementById("outputid");

for (var i = 0; i < obj.collection.length; i++) {                    
    if(obj.collection[i].lastAttr=="01") {
        out.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", obj.collection[i].firstAttr + " " + obj.collection[i].secAttr);
    }
}
```

Note that I used `==` instead of `=` for the comparison, and `.insertAdjacentHTML` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: I get "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup." as a error message.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the for loop. When deleting that I get a blank page, so it not writing to the p-block and the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace html try this

```
(someCollection) array;
 var r = new Array();
    var j = -1;
    r[++j] = '<ul class="list-group">';
    for (var i in array) {
        var d = array[i];
        if (d.attribute== somevalue) {
            r[++j] = '<li class="list-group-item">'
            r[++j]=d.otherattribute;
            r[++j] = '</li>';
        }
    }
    r[++j] = '</ul>';
    //for(var b in r) //alert to see the entire html code
    //{ alert(r[b]);}
    firstLoadOnPage = false;
    var list = document.getElementById('SymptomSection');
    list.innerHTML = r.join('');
```

this replaces the inside of element with classname "SymptomSection"